# A strange phenomenon on ST_Intersection() in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

here is my sql

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT
      ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(121.3457497 31.2595032,121.3476661 31.2588803,121.3483045 31.2586394,121.3486656 31.2584648,121.3496591 31.2581341,121.3502901 31.2579448,121.3508372 31.2577572,121.3510431 31.2576924,121.3513412 31.2575992,121.3521122 31.2573528,121.3528257 31.2571763,121.3540762 31.2567936,121.3545455 31.256655,121.3556707 31.2563493,121.3572948 31.2559062,121.3585218 31.2555803,121.3624269 31.2545252,121.3638771 31.2541136,121.3643317 31.2540021,121.3655331 31.2536892)') AS l1,
      ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(121.3509346 31.258821,121.3507514 31.2584162,121.3498022 31.2564959)') AS l2
)
  , t2 AS (
    SELECT st_intersection(l1, l2) AS p
    FROM t1
)
SELECT
  st_astext(st_intersection(l1, p)),
  st_astext(st_intersection(l2, p))
FROM t1, t2;
```

- t1 create two Linestrings l1, l2
- t2 calculate intersection point p

after that, I calculate the intersection of l1/l2 and p, but why the result is **empty**

[image]

Comment: Intersecting a point with a line is a matter of accuracy.

Comment: put st_snaptolerance around the geometries. I am currently having a major issue intersecting lines in postgis as well :( https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264440/postgis-linestring-to-linestring-intersection-miscalculations?noredirect=1#comment419574_264440

Comment: This would do it: `st_astext(st_intersection(l1, st_snap(p,l1,0.001)))`